# Encrypt multiple XML elements into a single block of data?

Tags: .net, xml, encryption

I am working through Microsoft's [How to: Decrypt XML Elements with Symmetric Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-decrypt-xml-elements-with-symmetric-keys).  In their example that take

```
<root>  
    <creditcard>  
        <number>19834209</number>  
        <expiry>02/02/2002</expiry>  
    </creditcard>  
</root>
```

And encrypt the `<creditcard>` element with a call to

```
byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, Key, false);
```

Which results in

```
<root>
  <EncryptedData ...
</root>
```

So that the complete `<creditcard>` element has been replaced with the encrypted data.

However in my case I have xml data in this format:

```
<root>
  <main>
    <sub1> ... </sub1>
    <sub2> ... </sub2>
    <sub3> ... </sub3>
  </main>
</root>
```

And I want to encrypt `<sub1>`, `<sub2>` and `<sub3>` into a single block of encrypted data, *but* leave `<main>` as is.  EG I want to end up with:

```
<root>
  <main>
    <EncryptedData ....
  </main>
<root>
```

Is this possible to do without first re-arranging my xml, or do I need to consolidate the elements that I want to encrypt into a dummy element and encrypt that?  EG do I have to temporarily build this xml and encrypt the `<dummy>` element?

```
<root>
  <main>
    <dummy>
      <sub1> ... </sub1>
      <sub2> ... </sub2>
      <sub3> ... </sub3>
    </dummy>
  </main>
</root>
```

Comment: Is there a method available that encrypts only the contents of an XML node and not its tag as well?

Comment: @DavidRTribble As far as I can see there is only the ability to encrypt an element.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If I do that I end up with 3 `<EncryptedData>` elements in my XML and  only want to have 1 such element. BTW this is an example layout.  In real life they are not called `<sub1>` etc, but have totally different names (but that is not an issue)

Comment: Ah, yeah, overlooked that requirement. No consolidating the elements (could possibly be done with a XSLT stylesheet?) would be the logical thing to do; encryption itself *should* not be used to change the structure of the XML document, that would be an unexpected side result and goes straight against the principle of least surprise. I'd be very surprised if that kind of functionality would be included into any API by design (and if it was, I'd still not use it).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Unfortunately I am trying to replicate existing functionality :(

Comment: You can still do it with an additional step, as long as there is no need for another party to accept the *encrypted* XML.